# can't deploy (checkout) code and branch still missing after shallow git fetch

Tags: git, deployment, fetch, git-fetch, shallow-clone

I've made a quick setup of the repository:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:bbaccount/svgopt.git
git fetch origin display-channel --depth 1
remote: Counting objects: 85, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (82/82), done.
remote: Total 85 (delta 5), reused 47 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (85/85), done.
From bitbucket.org:bbaccount/svgopt
 * branch            display-channel -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Then, when I'm trying to get the code:

```
git checkout display-channel
```

I get:

```
error: pathspec 'display-channel' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I've checked and despite the `git fetch` log output the branch doesn't seem to be locally avaliable:

```
git branch -a
```

returns nothing. I'm looking to get the most recent code from single branch only (no reason to pull all) - can I not do that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution myself. Should have used:

```
git checkout display-channel:display-channel
```

instead so it adds/updates the branch:

```
remote: Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
From bitbucket.org:bbaccount/svgopt
* [new branch]      display-channel -> display-channel
```